# cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: 64-bit Oracle Client library cannot be loaded: "dlopen(libclntsh.dylib, 1): image not found"

Tags: python, python-2.7, cx-oracle

I am trying to set up `cx_Oracle` to work with Python.

I am using

- Python 2.7.10, 64-bit
- `cx_Oracle` version 6.0.2
- MacOS Sierra 10.12.6

I set the following environment variables:

```shell
export ORACLE_HOME="/Volumes/DATA/Programs/PY/instantclient_12_1"
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="$ORACLE_HOME:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME
export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME
export ORACLE_SID=edocd
export TNS_ADMIN=/Volumes/DATA/Programs/PY/instantclient_12_1/network/admin
export TWO_TASK=${ORACLE_SID}
```

Here is what I tried:

1. Installed as Administrator
2. `sudo python setup.py build`
3. `sudo python setup.py install`

When I tried to execute a simple script to check the Oracle connection I was able to connect successfully via `sqlplus`.

Here is the error I receive:

> cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: 64-bit Oracle Client library cannot be loaded: "dlopen(libclntsh.dylib, 1): image not found". See https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#macos for help

Comment: Did you follow the instructions found at the link found in the error message?

Answer (score 7):

**My solution for Ubuntu 16.04 (64bit)**

A **tl;dr:** of the [official guide](https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#macos):

1) Download the [instantclient-basic-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html)

2) Extract it to /opt/oracle directory:

```sh
$ sudo mkdir -p /opt/oracle
$ cd /opt/oracle
$ unzip ~/Downloads/instantclient-basic-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip
```

3) Install **libaio** package

```sh
$ sudo apt-get install libaio1
```

4) Edit the *oracle-instantclient.conf* file like so:

```sh
$ sudo sh -c "echo /opt/oracle/instantclient_12_2 > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf"
$ sudo ldconfig
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but the question was about macOS.  The solution is different to Linux.

Answer (score 4):

link `${your_instantclient_folder}` -> `${oracle_home}/lib`

```
cd ${ORACLE_HOME};
unzip instantclient-basic-macos.x64-x.x.x.zip
ln -s instantclient_X_X lib
```

[reference](https://github.com/oracle/odpi/blob/v2.4.2/src/dpiOci.c#L1563)

Answer (score 1):

Install cx_Oracle in Virtualenv

Preconditions.

```
Python 2.7.10, 64-bit
cx_Oracle version 6.0.2
MacOS Sierra 10.12.6
```

Oracle client installed by instructions https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#macos in

```
/opt/oracle/instantclient_12_1
```

Add to your ~/.bash_profile:

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/instantclient_12_1
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME
export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME:$PATH
```

Try Virtualenv

```
1. virtualenv ~/venv
2. source ~/venv/bin/activate
3. pip install IPython (Optional. I prefer IPython)
4. pip install cx_Oracle

(venv) ~$ pip install cx_Oracle
Collecting cx_Oracle
Installing collected packages: cx-Oracle
Successfully installed cx-Oracle-6.0.2

(venv) ~$ IPython
Python 2.7.10 (default, Feb  7 2017, 00:08:15) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 5.4.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: import cx_Oracle

In [2]: con = cx_Oracle.connect('system/manager@orasrv/orcl')

In [3]: cur = con.cursor()
   ...: 
   ...: select = ("SELECT * FROM tbl1")
   ...: cur.execute(select)
   ...: 
Out[3]: <cx_Oracle.Cursor on <cx_Oracle.Connection to system@orasrv/orcl>>

In [4]: for row in cur:
   ...:     print(row)
   ...:
```

Comment: With current macOS versions, SIP will stop DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH being read form subshells, so it doesn't really help and doesn't need to be set.  LD_LIBRARY_PATH is redundant on macOS.   And with Oracle Instant Client (and cx_Oracle 6), you shouldn't set ORACLE_HOME.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @anthony-tuininga's answer: the URL in the error message has the steps to follow. See https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#macos Specifically make sure the Oracle client libraries are in ~/lib or /usr/local/lib.
Don't set DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH or LD_LIBRARY_PATH or ORACLE_HOME.

Comment: This actually helped. [Ubuntu 16.04 64bit | PyCharm 2017.3CE]

Answer (score 0):

For me

`source ~/.profile`

was the **skipped step** while installing.

Answer (score 0):

I followed these steps and it worked for me in MacOS.

Followed instruction inside the following link to download Oracle Instant Client for MacOS

https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/downloads.html

And added following into ./bash_profile file located inside home directory.

```
export ORACLE_HOME= <path to Oracle Instant Client folder>(I used instantclient_19_8)
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME
export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME:$PATH
```

And installed cx_Oracle library using conda.

https://anaconda.org/anaconda/cx_oracle

Also here's an example to try in Jupyter Notebook to verify that it installed correctly.

https://krinkere.github.io/krinkersite/connect_to_oracle_via_python.html

Comment: Never set `ORACLE_HOME` with Instant Client.  It has a different purpose.  Since setting the library loading path variables is "broken" on macOS, normally I don't set any environment variables (except `PATH`) but instead add this to my code: `import sys, os
if sys.platform.startswith("darwin"):
    cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client(lib_dir=os.environ.get("HOME")+"/Downloads/instantclient_19_8")`