# Error "DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library" when connecting to Oracle Database with Python3 (cx_Oracle) using instant client

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I'm trying to connect to an Oracle database from a python script that runs on an Oracle linux 7 machine where Oracle instant client (12.2) is installed.
The client installation seems to be fine, I can do

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0.1/client
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${ORACLE_HOME}/bin:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"
$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus <username>/***@<connection_string>
```

and it works.
When I export ORACLE_HOME and LD_LIBRARY_PATH before executing my python script, the script works as well.
The point is: I want to set these variables within the python script. I've tried

```
os.environ["ORACLE_HOME"] = "/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0.1/client"
```

and then

```
os.environ["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"] = "/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0.1/client/bin"
```

or (with some try-except-block around it)

```
os.environ["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"] = "/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0.1/client/bin:" + os.environ["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"]
```

at the very beginning of the script, but I keep getting errors like

```
DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "libmql1.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory".
```

I've also let the python script print out the LD_LIBRARY variable before setting up the database connection -- and it shows the right value. It seems to me that the "export" of the variable somehow doesn't work, as if the calling of the Oracle client doesn't get the right data.

If you have any idea what I could try or test please don't hesitate to write it here. I'd be glad to get new input on that problem.
Regards,

Katharina

PS: Yes, I know, I shouldn't set ORACLE_HOME on a server where there's no real Oracle home installed. Please don't focus on that.

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues/55) or 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46098562/cx-oracle-databaseerror-dpi-1047-64-bit-oracle-client-library-cannot-be-loaded/48884444)
 answer your question ..?

Comment: From the install path, it looks like you have a 'full' client, so setting ORACLE_HOME is required because it will be referenced to find data files like the message files.  Only if you had Oracle Instant Client would you not set ORACLE_HOME.

Comment: I set that install path by myself so that I can use the same path independently of whether it's a database server or just a client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is **only** examined when the process starts up. You cannot set that value wthin the process and expect it to be examined when the Oracle Client library is searched for.

You have a few options if you don't want to set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable. You can:

- add to `/etc/ld.so.conf` configuration the location of the Oracle Client library. This will be configured for all users of the machine
- create a script that sets `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and then calls your Python program and call the script instead of your Python program
- although this is not technically supported, it does work -- use `chrpath` or `patchelf` to change the `RPATH` of the Oracle Client library to be the location where it is found or the value `$ORIGIN`. Once this is done you can use `cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client()` to specify that location directly

Comment: I tried `chrpath -l /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0.1/client/bin/sqlplus`, but it says `no rpath or runpath tag found.`. What exactly do you mean by "change RPATH of the Oracle Client library"?

Comment: You want to change the rpath of $ORACLE_HOME/lib/libclntsh.so, not of SQL*Plus!

Comment: I tried `patchelf` instead and that worked. Thank you very much! If you add `patchelf` to your answer I would mark your answer as "solved problem".

Comment: Yes, patchelf is another solution and I have added it to the answer as suggested. Thanks!